# FFTW log-log plot

Tags: fft, c++

I am taking a real-time `fft` of an audio signal using `fftw` library. I take the output of the `fftw` signal on $y$-axis and plot it against the linear frequency bins on $x$-axis.

I've noticed that spectrum analyzers use a skewed `plot(log plot)`. I can get my $y$-axis (`magnitude`) into $\rm dB$ by doing `20*log(magnitude)` but I don't know how to get my frequency axis($x$-axis) into log-scale. I need some help in doing that in C/C++ not Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

You interpolate between the bins such that they map to your output grid (you may even need this for any kind of display where your output pixels doesn't match your transform size).

You will get the best result using sinc-interpolation on both the real and imaginary outputs (or just magnitude if you don't care). Look up lanczos interpolation for a smaller, windowed version.

To transform your x-axis into a exponential scale, you can use a mapping function like this:

```
min * (max/min) ^ x
```

where x is between 0 and 1, and max is the end of the graph - usually samplerate / 2. The graph starts at min. Here's the inverse function:

```
log(y/min) / log(max/min)
```

Comment: the interpolation will be "grainy" down in the low octaves.

Comment: Define 'grainy'. Sinc/lanczos will make it perfectly smooth, although the technical time/frequency resolution will stay constant, of course.

Comment: well, the interpolation between widely-spaced points will be smooth, but the points from the FFT are more sparsely-spaced in the log-frequency scale at low frequencies than at high frequencies.  a polished craggy landscape is still craggy.  otherwise there is nothing preventing one from selecting an FFT length $N$ as small as one wants and just interpolating between the points for whatever resolution they want to think they are getting.

Comment: Well, that's an interpretation of terms. Mathematically, it will be perfectly smooth (and correct). By your definition, all interpolations are grainy. That's implied, when you interpolate. 

The actual information content ('resolution') will stay bandlimited and constant, as I said.

Comment: no, you're not correct.  Mathematically it may be "smooth" (given the normal metric for defining "smoothness" of a function), but not necessarily correct.  given a consistent scale and resolution in log-frequency (which is the scale that you are viewing the "smoothness" of the output of the FFT), there is an implication in the lower octaves of more resolution than you really have. if you used a longer FFT (with more data) you could get virtual agreement at the high frequencies, but something that looks very different at low frequencies compared to what you have with fewer, sparser points.

Comment: The implication of more resolution is irrelevant, the actual lobe widths get larger, thus satisfying the time/frequency resolution aspect. Thats like arguing a smooth continuous sine wave is not correct just because it 'only' needs to be described by > 2 points/cycle. The shape and width of bins match sinc functions, because, well, that's what they are. The interpolation will reveal this true shape. Thus, interpolating using sinc will be *correct*.

I have never said it *added* any information, that's why I emphasized twice that the time/frequency resolution stays constant.

Comment: Could you explain what is `x` in your first formula? Is it going in a loop from 0 to 1, and with what step?